# How can I navigate from an inner component to outer component react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I really need some helps, can't think of a solution :(. I have a problem like this: For example, I'm inside a route called, `http://localhost:3000/quiz/draft`. I want to go to `http://localhost:3000/quiz/142a99fc-beb8-4de5-96c5-311cae372287`. But whenever I use `Link` or `history` inside the nested component, it keeps on appending to the url `http://localhost:3000/quiz/draft/142a99fc-beb8-4de5-96c5-311cae372287`.

This is my code.

App component

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navigation />
      {currentUser ? <MenuSide /> : null }
      <Switch>

        <Route path="/quiz" render={props => (!currentUser) ? <Redirect to="/login" /> : <QuizPage {...props} /> } />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

QuizPage component

```
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path={`${match.path}/:uuid`} render={props => <QuizDetailView {...props} /> } />
            <Route exact path={`${match.path}/dashboard`} render={props => <QuizDashboard {...props} />} />
            <Route exact path={`${match.path}/center`} render={props => <QuizCenter {...props} /> } />
            <Route exact path={`${match.path}/draft`} render={props => <QuizDraftCenter {...props} /> } />
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

And inside `QuizDraftCenter`, I have a component that want to navigate to `/quiz/:uuid`

```
    const { title, displayname, created, is_published, uuid } = userQuiz;
    return (
        <div className="quiz-center-item">
            <div className="item-container-1">
                <span className="title">{title}</span>
                <span className={`publish-status ${is_published ? 'green' : 'yellow'}`}>
                    {(is_published) ? 'Published' : 'Draft'}
                </span>
            </div>
            <div className="item-container-2">
                <span className="creator">{displayname}</span>
                <span className="created">{new Date(created).toLocaleString()}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="item-container-3">
                <button className="quiz-button edit" onClick={() => history.push(`${match.url}/${uuid}`)}>EDIT</button>
                <button className="quiz-button delete">DELETE</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This takes the current window location path, removes the part after the last backslash and adds a new string (uuid):

```
<button className="quiz-button edit" onClick={() => history.push(this.props.location.pathname.split('/').slice(0,-1).join('/') + uuid)}>EDIT</button>
```

More info on react-router `location` object: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/location.md